# Refused to apply style from 'https://codepen.io/... because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported

Tags: codepen

I'm trying to create a codepen that references a base template to use for for multiple projects.
I get the below error message when I look at the colsole.

*Refused to apply style from 'https://codepen.io/... because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.*

What I've done:

- Created my template with references to various js and css CDN's.
- Placed in the HTML section of codepen some demo code.
- added some @font-face code for css.

This is the code that is presented when clicking on the error message in the console.
In the Pen that is referencing the template all I added was an H2 tag.

I don't understand why I'm getting the error message.

````
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" href="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-5ae1a0698dcc2402e9712f7d01ed509a57814f994c660df9f7a952f3060705ee.png" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="CodePen">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-aec34940fbc1a6e787974dcd360f2c6b63348d4b1f4e06c77743096d55480f33.ico" />
<link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-8f3771b1072e3c38bd662872f6b673a722f4b3ca2421637d5596661b4e2132cc.svg" color="#111" />

<title>CodePen - A Pen by Me</title>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://codepen.io/pen/?template=abc'>
</head>

<body translate="no" >
  <h2>hello</h2>
  <script src='https://codepen.io/pen/?template=ABCDEF'></script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting up a proxy vis heroku.com and using that as a relay.